# Scraping each image from a craigslist search

Tags: python, image, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, src

I'm trying to pull each image url from a craigslist search, but can't seem to drill down to the URL itself.  When I try `soup.find_all("a", { "class":"result-image gallery"} )[0].img`, it doesn't return anything.

Specifically, the page I am trying to scrape is https://raleigh.craigslist.org/search/rea?query=duplex&sort=date&availabilityMode=0&sale_date=all+dates.

I'm trying to get the image at the following `src`: https://images.craigslist.org/00j0j_cC4PhAMdHLj_300x300.jpg

The super frustrating thing is that I was able to successfully do this yesterday, but didn't commit that working code to Github at the time.  I have since accidentally deleted it and can't figure out what I had originally done to make this work :(

Comment: the image is on the other page: https://raleigh.craigslist.org/reo/d/rocky-mount-off-market-multifamily/6892616013.html,  you need to go there and then find image

Comment: ohmygosh... duh!  That makes sense  Thanks for your help!

Comment: you don't have to leave the landing page.

Answer (score 2):

You should try automation `selenium` library. it allows you to **scrape** dynamic rendering request(js or ajax) page data.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from bs4.element import Tag

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://raleigh.craigslist.org/search/rea?query=duplex&sort=date&availabilityMode=0&sale_date=all+dates')
time.sleep(3)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
rowArray = soup.find_all("li", { "class":"result-row"})

for row in rowArray:
    img = row.find("img")
    if img is None:
        continue
    if isinstance(img,Tag) and img.has_attr("src"):
        print(img['src'])
        print("----------------")
```

O/P:

```
https://images.craigslist.org/00U0U_azwRntzeNXr_300x300.jpg
----------------
https://images.craigslist.org/00101_h0xsGArMWPh_300x300.jpg
----------------
https://images.craigslist.org/00J0J_2EzptPF9ysn_300x300.jpg
----------------
https://images.craigslist.org/00101_2FiqAHsu509_300x300.jpg
----------------
https://images.craigslist.org/00D0D_jQbpUTsk6o3_300x300.jpg
```

where `'/usr/bin/chromedriver'` selenium web driver path.

**Download selenium web driver for chrome browser:**

http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

**Install web driver for chrome browser:**

https://christopher.su/2015/selenium-chromedriver-ubuntu/

**Selenium tutorial:**

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 1):

You only need requests and the landing page.

You can construct from the ids on the page (And get all the images for each property)

The `data-ids` attribute provides a list of the ids for the associated images which you can use to construct each image url.

```html
<a href="https://raleigh.craigslist.org/reo/d/rocky-mount-off-market-multifamily/6892616013.html" class="result-image gallery" data-ids="1:00j0j_cC4PhAMdHLj"><img alt="" class="" src="https://images.craigslist.org/00j0j_cC4PhAMdHLj_300x300.jpg">
    <span class="result-price">$99000</span>
</a>
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

image_url = 'https://images.craigslist.org/{}_300x300.jpg'
r = requests.get('https://raleigh.craigslist.org/search/rea?query=duplex&sort=date&availabilityMode=0&sale_date=all+dates')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
ids = [item['data-ids'].replace('1:','') for item in soup.select('.result-image[data-ids]')] 
images = [image_url.format(j) for i in ids for j in i.split(',')]
print(images)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to get only the first image url. Therefore, you can just use `find` instead of `find_all`.

Also, to get the URL, you need to get the `src` attribute from `img` as well.

```py
soup.find("a", { "class":"result-image gallery"} ).img["src"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    r = requests.get("url here")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features="html.parser")
    image_link = soup.find("div", { "class":"slide first visible"} ).img["src"]
```

You may have to change the tag type (div) and the class identifier if craigslist changes the html layout.